# Offset Transform on top of Alembic Transform Cache

Tags: alembic

I have a Blender scene in which it has Alembic Transform Cache constraining the object. Somewhat the constraint is locking all transform and I wanted to be able to offset the transform like rotating, scaling or even reposition the object. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this at the moment is to  add a Copy Transform constraint, check its Offset checkbox, and let it target an Empty. The Empty can then control the offset.